# Integer Linear Least Squares

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

So I have to find a x that minimizes `norm(A.dot(x) - y, 2)` A is a matrix and y is a vector.

This could be easily accomplished with `scipy.optimize.lsq_linear` or `numpy.linalg.lstsq` but I need x to be integers. In general "Integer programming" is NP-complete. 
I did find [Routines for solving the standard integer least squares problem](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~chang/MILES_routine1.php) but I thought I'd ask before I convert it from matlab.

Is there an established library that can solve the Integer Linear Least Squares in python?

Comment: @ruakh, thanks forgot that. lol.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html

Comment: @sinewaver, lstsq returns floats. I was hoping to find the best integer solution.

Comment: check here https://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific/Libraries

Comment: Did you ever get around to implementing the MILES package in python?

Comment: I did not, I used the other suggestions in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one of the optimization libraries available for python than can handle (mixed) integer programming. Do a google search and you will find many. Since your problem is convex, `cvxpy` can be used as a nice interface to many of them. Here's a toy example using a built-in integer programming solver (which may not be very efficient for large scale problems)

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy

np.random.seed(123) # for reproducability

# generate A and y
m, n = 10, 10
A = np.random.randn(m,n)
y = np.random.randn(m)

# declare the integer-valued optimization variable
x = cvxpy.Int(n)

# set up the L2-norm minimization problem
obj = cvxpy.Minimize(cvxpy.norm(A * x - y, 2))
prob = cvxpy.Problem(obj)

# solve the problem using an appropriate solver
sol = prob.solve(solver = 'ECOS_BB')

# the optimal value of x is 
print(x.value)
```

> ```
> [[-13.]
>  [ -3.]
>  [  3.]
>  [  6.]
>  [  1.]
>  [ -5.]
>  [ -1.]
>  [ -3.]
>  [ -2.]
>  [ -6.]]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I did come up with a related solution solving sum(|Ax-y|) which you can convert into a linear integer programming problem and solve using PuLP.

The basic idea is to minimize the objective function sum(err(i)) subject to the constraints:

Ax(i) - y(i) <= err(i)  and   Ax(i) - y(i) >= -err(i).

which is compatible with linear solvers.